# Unset multidimensional array where indexis presented as string

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got an array that looks like this:

```
'coilovers' => 
  'strut_and_individual_components' => 
      'complete_strut' => 
          0 => 
            array (size=5)
              'achse' => string 'Oś tylnia' (length=10)
              'position' => string 'Prawo' (length=5)
              'material' => string 'Stal' (length=4)
              'variante' => string 'Wariant 3' (length=9)
              'img' => string 'gewindefahrwerk_federbein_komplett_level3.png'         
'hls_components' =>
  'assembly_pump_unit' => 
      0 => 
          'achse' => string 'Assembly pump unit' (length=18)
          'img' => string 'hls_komponenten_baugruppe_pumpeneinheit_level3.png'
```

Now I'm getting string parameter that looki for example like : [coilovers][strut_and_individual_components][complete_strut][0]

And now I want to to unset whole branch of that array based on that parameter. So far I've accomplished how to read value but that parameter and it looks like.

```
private function str_index_array(&$arr, $indexes) {

    $arr_indexes = explode('][',trim($indexes,'[]'));

    $session_array = &$arr;
    foreach($arr_indexes as $index) {
        $session_array = &$session_array[$index];
    }

}
```

But I'm stuck now, I need to check if that element is last element in array and in previous element is that previous element is empty if its empty unset whole brunch. Any ideas?

Comment: So what you are trying to do is unset 'coilovers' for example?

Comment: I want to do smth line unset($arr[coilovers][strut_and_individual_components][complete_strut][0]) and if $arr[coilovers][strut_and_individual_components][complete_strut] is empty unset($arr[coilovers][strut_and_individual_components][complete_strut])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure some PHP/array/reference expert can come up with better ways of doing this, but here is one bug-ugly solution. I've set up a loop to obtain a reference to the last but second level index, and test and delete the sub-indexes from there. Note that there is no error-checking to test if the indexes actually exist before using them.

```
<?php

$a = array (
       'coilovers' => array (
         'strut_and_individual_components' => array (
           'complete_strut' => array (
             0 => array (
               'achse' => 'Os tylnia',
               'position' => 'Prawo',
               'material' => 'Stal',
               'variante' => 'Wariant 3',
               'img' => 'gewindefahrwerk_federbein_komplett_level3.png'
             )
           )
         )
       ),
       'hls_components' => array (
         'assembly_pump_unit' => array (
           0 => array (
            'achse' => 'Assembly pump unit',
            'img' => 'hls_komponenten_baugruppe_pumpeneinheit_level3.png'  
           )
         )
       )
     );

function delete_index (&$arr, $indexes) {

    $arr_indexes = explode('][',trim($indexes,'[]'));

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr_indexes) - 2; $i++) {
      $arr = &$arr[$arr_indexes[$i]];
    }
    $ix1 = $arr_indexes[$i];
    $ix2 = $arr_indexes[$i+1];

    unset ($arr[$ix1][$ix2]);
    if (empty ($arr[$ix1]))
      unset ($arr[$ix1]);
}

print_r ($a);
delete_index ($a, '[coilovers][strut_and_individual_components][complete_strut][0]');
print_r ($a);
```